# I am trying to extract data as HTML elements in python using pdfminer

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdfminer, pdf-conversion, pdf-to-html

I am trying extract data as HTML from pdf using pdfminer although I was successful to extract text from the same pdf now I am getting an error while extracting data as HTML I have to filter the data further to categorize it in CSV. This is the script.

```py
from io import StringIO  
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams  
from pdfminer.high_level import extract_text_to_fp  

output_string = StringIO  

with open('mini.pdf','rb') as fn:  
    extract_text_to_fp(fn, output_string, laparams=LAParams(), output_type='html', codec=None)
```

And this is the error I am getting.
[Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0BPg.jpg)

Comment: What version of pdfminer and python are you running? I can't find this 'extract_text_to_fp' method that you import in the current distribution. To verify, run "pip show pdfminer".

Comment: Help us help you, edit your question to include the error as text, instead of linked image

Comment: I was able to solve the error I used a file object instead of output string and it helped.

Comment: I am using pdfminer.six and I was able to import it using just pdfminer.

Answer (score 2):

Add parentheses to `StringIO` this way: `output_string = StringIO()`  that will call the class construction, and code could get working with this